# "is mainly that between creditors and debtors" or "is mainly which between creditors and debtors"

Tags: pronouns, that-vs-which

I have written the following sentence:

> The relationship between banks and depositors is mainly **that** between creditors and debtors.

First, I want to ask whether it is correct to use that in such situation.
Second, if it is correct, I also hope to know whethet that can be substitute by which.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence:

- The relationship between banks and depositors is mainly **that** between creditors and debtors.

is correct.

The pronoun "that" could be replaced with "the one" (meaning, "the relationship"), but not with "which". However, "which" could be used if what follows "that" were expanded into a relative clause:

- The relationship between banks and depositors is mainly **that which / the one that/which** exists between creditors and debtors.